# cocoa:When the button is pressed，Move the mouse，Do not drag the window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion

When the button is pressed，Move the mouse，Do not drag the window.

When the button is pressed to move , do not move the window

The code download. http://code.google.com/p/kacperwangbuttontab/downloads/detail?name=buttonTab.zip&can=2&q=#makechanges

Button to add a class **ButtonStyle**.Pressed the mouse to change the background image.

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
            [self setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"closeDown.png"]];
}
```

[image]

**Here is the code of dragging the window**

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{ 
    NSRect  windowFrame = [self frame];
    initialLocation = [NSEvent mouseLocation];

    initialLocation.x -= windowFrame.origin.x;
    initialLocation.y -= windowFrame.origin.y;   
}
- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSPoint currentLocation;
    NSPoint newOrigin;

    NSRect  screenFrame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
    NSRect  windowFrame = [self frame];

    currentLocation = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
    newOrigin.x = currentLocation.x - initialLocation.x;
    newOrigin.y = currentLocation.y - initialLocation.y;
    if( (newOrigin.y+windowFrame.size.height) > (screenFrame.origin.y+screenFrame.size.height) ){
        newOrigin.y=screenFrame.origin.y + (screenFrame.size.height-windowFrame.size.height);
    }
    [self setFrameOrigin:newOrigin];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Click the button to move the window does not move.I move the window。

Comment: Do you want to move the window only when the mouseDown is over the button? or when the mouse is anywhere in the window?

Comment: The code download.When the button is pressed to move , do not move the window

Comment: If you have a friend that can translate for you, please do so, as your post in its current form makes zero sense.

Comment: I'm sorry，I don't want drag the window when i push the button to move，ButtonTab Example , I update.what should we do.Understand this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what it is that you want, but if you want the window to not drag when you click and drag over the button, adding one line, [super mouseDown:theEvent];, to your mouseDown method in the ButtonStyle class seems to do it.

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    switch (self.tag) {
        case 2:
            [self setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"closeDown.png"]];
            [super mouseDown:theEvent];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Press the button will not be able to set the picture .

Comment: When I press the button it does change the picture

Comment: You set a background , you will find the button does not change the background .I downloaded the updated files , set the background for you to test .

Comment: Which app are we talking about here?  ButtonHover or ButtonTab?  The last time I downloaded I got ButtonHover, the current link downloads ButtonTab.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help any more because I can't understand your english.

Comment: I'm sorry，I don't want drag the window when i push the button to move，ButtonTab Example , I update.what should we do